# Mark eternal orchestration as unsuccessful in Azure

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have this eternal orchestration:

```
public class SchedulingOrchestration : BaseOrchestration
{
    private readonly SchedulingOrchestrationOptions _schedulingOrchestrationOptions;

    public SchedulingOrchestration(IOptions<SchedulingOrchestrationOptions> schedulingOrchestrationOptions, ILogger<SchedulingOrchestration> logger) : base(logger)
    {
        this._schedulingOrchestrationOptions = schedulingOrchestrationOptions.Value;
    }

    [Function(nameof(SchedulingOrchestration))]
    public async Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        var sleepTime = this._schedulingOrchestrationOptions.SleepTime;

        this.Logger.LogInformation("Executing {OrchestrationName} with instance id {InstanceId} and sleep time {SleepPeriod}",
            nameof(SchedulingOrchestration), context.InstanceId, sleepTime);

        try
        {
            var tenantInfo = new TenantInfo { Id = context.InstanceId };
        
            var schedulesPendingPaymentResult = await context.CallActivityAsync<OperationResult<IEnumerable<long>>>(nameof(GetSchedulesPendingPayment), tenantInfo);

            if (!schedulesPendingPaymentResult.Success || schedulesPendingPaymentResult.ResultObject == default)
            {
                this.Logger.LogError("{FunctionName} failed to retrieve schedules pending payment for tenant id {TenantId}",
                    nameof(GetSchedulesPendingPayment), tenantInfo.Id);
            }
            else
            {
                var schedulesPendingPayment = schedulesPendingPaymentResult.ResultObject;

                this.Logger.LogInformation("{OrchestrationName} found {SchedulesCount} schedules pending payment for tenant id {TenantId}",
                    nameof(SchedulingOrchestration), schedulesPendingPayment.Count(), tenantInfo.Id);
        
                var tasks = schedulesPendingPayment.Select(scheduleId => context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(CreateAndEnqueuePayment), new ScheduleDto(scheduleId, tenantInfo)));

                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Logger.LogError(ex, "Unexpected exception while running {OrchestrationName}", nameof(SchedulingOrchestration));
            context.SetCustomStatus("Failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            // sleep between executions
            var nextExecution = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(sleepTime);
            await context.CreateTimer(nextExecution, CancellationToken.None);

            context.ContinueAsNew();
        }
    }
}
```

I have added the try catch because I don't want the orchestration to stop on exception. However, I want to see it marked as "Failed" in Azure logs without having to manually start it again.

I did try removing the catch but that just stops the orchestration from running again. Also, I tried setting a custom status but that didn't do the trick as this is what I see in Azure:
[image]